# How do I prevent cheating when user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

So I wanted to develop a small clicker game to get my feet wet and it would also answer my question which I have in regards to cheating.

So this is the concept there is a blank page with a `Button` and a `<h1/>`
There will be a registration process and the user will get put in a databse with a `Score` column as well as the Username & password etc.

When the user clicks on the `Button` I want to add a point to that user that then gets put into the `Score` column in the databse so that the score gets saved and also displays on the page in the `h1` tag

Now if I do it through JavaScript, accessing the database through the Client and adding points from the Client then that feels like I would invite nothing but cheaters and a lot of security issues.

So my question is.
How do I prevent cheaters by maybe creating a button and then hooking that up with a Function in my `Controller` so I can deal with it server sided.

```
<body>
    <h1>Playground</h1>

    <h1>Points @Model.Coins</h1>

    <h1 id="Points">0</h1>

    <button id="PointsButton">Points!</button>

    <script src="~/js/PointSystem.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS

```
let i = 1;
let button = document.getElementById("PointsButton");
let DisplayPoints = document.getElementById("Points").innerHTML;
DisplayPoints = i;

button.onclick = AddPoints;

function AddPoints() {

}
```

Comment: It sounds like the technology you're looking for is "AJAX".  Look for examples and tutorials of using AJAX in ASP.NET (MVC, Core, any other details of your server-side technology).

Comment: Anything you expose as client side code is vulnerable to hacking (HTML, CSS, JavaScript). To secure your database, you'd need server-side checks (.php, .aspx, .jsp).

Comment: I'll look into AJAX.

Comment: `window.setInterval(()=>button.click(),1000)` going to stop scripting??

Comment: @epascarello I'm not looking to set a interval, the user can click as fast as they want the issue is that I don't want them changing the DOM to where they will get => 1 point

Comment: @MarkDenom: His point is that *users* can set that interval and automatically click the button as fast as they want.  There's nothing to stop them.  The point is to stay realistic about "cheating" here.  Server-side validation can certainly help if you can define your validation logic.  But if the game were to become popular and people were to cheat, hopefully the server is ready to handle *a lot* of requests.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should rethink whether you need to stop cheaters, secondly anything you send to the client is ultimately hackable.

It sounds like you need something from the server that authenticates the transaction as legitimate.  How to do this semi-securely is really to broad of a question for this site,

If you ignore the security concern until it’s necessary, you can do this via XMLHttpRequest or fetch on newer browsers.